# Different return type inference for same implementation in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

I would like to understand why is there a type difference between the following 2 implementations. Both of them generate the same results but the return type for both of them varies.

```
const from = [
    () => console.log('first'), 
    () => console.log('second'), 
    () => console.log('third')];

const to = {
    first: 1,
    second: 2,
    third: 3,
};

const aggFn = (from: Function[], to: { [as: string]: any }): Record<keyof typeof to, Function> => {
    return ({
        first: from[0],
        second: from[1],
        third: from[2],
    } as unknown) as Record<keyof typeof to, Function>;
};

const agg = aggFn(from, to);
```

The return type of agg here is **Record<"string" | "number", Function>**, where as for the second code

```
const from = [
    () => console.log('first'), 
    () => console.log('second'), 
    () => console.log('third')];

const to = {
    first: 1,
    second: 2,
    third: 3,
};

const aggFn2 = <T>(from: Function[], to: { [as: string]: any }): T => {
    return ({
        first: from[0],
        second: from[1],
        third: from[2],
    } as unknown) as T;
};

const agg2 = aggFn2<Record<keyof typeof to, Function>>(from, to);
```

the return type is **Record<"first" | "second" | "third", Function>**

Comment: Because `to` in the first example is referring to the function parameter which shadows the `to` variable from the outer scope.

Comment: @jcalz Is there a way to get the type inference to return the type with actual keys of `to`  like `Record<"first" | "second" | "third", Function>` with the first implementation.
I am trying to figure out a way where the user does not have to pass the type while calling and achieve the same results. It will help in creating and passing the `to` object inline

Comment: Just don't shadow. :)

Comment: @JonasWilms Pardon me for being naive here. Do you mean not defining the `to` variable in the global scope and just as functional parameter? If so, even that leads to a type inference of type `Record<"string" | "number", Function>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `to` in the two versions of `typeof to` refer to different variables: In the first snippet it refers to the *local variable* of type `{ [as: string]: any }`, in the other one it refers to the *global variable* `to`. That variable was typed through the value assigned to it, which is of type `{ first: string, second: string, third: string }`.

The actual typing of the function should be (which actually fits it's behaviour, and it allows typescript to infer the generic argument based on the `to` argument):

```
  <T> (to: Record<T, any>): Record<T, Function>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I needed the return type to be complete for contextual typing I was able to get it working by changing the signature to `<T> (to: T): Record<keyof T, Function>`
Since now `T` is derived from `to`, I do not even need to pass the generics type